# CakePHP 2 and FullCalendar jQuery PlugIn - CSS conflict and save data asynchronous

Tags: jquery, cakephp, fullcalendar, cakephp-2.x

I encounter problems using CakePHP (2.5.9) in combination with FullCalendar plugin.

My first problem is, that the CSS layout from FullCalendar seems to interfere with cakephp CSS layout. If cake.generic.css is loaded, the calendar view ist broken(the calendar does not fit into the container div, the cells have wrong sizes and therefore the durations of the appointments are not ending at the correct time, the cells overlap partially, etc.). If I disable cake.generic.css everything looks fine, but then I have broken cake views(even a simple radio form element looks horrible).

How can I tell cakephp to use cake.generic.css and FullCalendar to only use its own fullcalendar.css?

My second problem is, that I 'm not sure how to combine the cakephp form mechanism with AJAX mechanism. So if I want to create an appointment by clicking into the timeline, I think it should be possible to show the desired form fields in front of the calendar and without redirect to a view with a cakephp form. What is the easiest approach to save form data asynchronous with cakephp form validation? I think I have to do something like this:

- create form inputs with 'required'=>false
- display UI Dialog(which contains the form inputs)
- collect data of all fields by IDs
- send serialized data to cakephp action(AJAX)
- in cakephp action test for invalidFields()
- if validation fails, send json_encoded validation errors back to AJAX success function
- in AJAX success function iterate the errors and assign them to the
  corresponding form IDs

Is there a better way to accomplish asynchronous form saving with validation?

Answer (score 0):

Css conflict:

1. load cake.generic.css / or any other css framework
2. load fullcalendar css / or any other plugins css
3. load your custom css

Second problem.

It's old tutorial but read this http://duckranger.com/2010/03/fullcalendar-and-cakephp-part-1-set-up/